# CSS "display: flex"/row problems in Firefox (using bootsrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox, compatibility

A site I am working on displays correctly in all broswers (IE, Chrome, Safari, Mobile) except Firefox.

In all browsers (except Firefox) the content within the **div class="vertical-center"** is center aligned on the x-axis and fills the full width of the page:

However, in Firefox, the **div class="row"** is squished to the left of the page**:

Is there a way around this that has the same end result? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<section> 
    <div class="vertical-center">
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Row should fill width of "section", but does not in Firefox -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.vertical-center {
min-height: 50%;
min-height: 50vh;
display: flex; /* This causes a problem, but is required for proper display*/
align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: It appears to work for me [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h3zxmw6x/). Do you mind creating an example reproducing the issue?

Comment: I removed most of the code for simplicity.

Comment: I think you will have to use `margin: 0 auto` to get `center` align https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/217/

Comment: Also you have 2 `min-height` so pick one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Firefox does not calculate properly the width of the `div.row`, being a block element it should be 100%.

So you need to set it on your own.

```
.vertical-center .row { width:100%; }
```